# Error: Body must be a string. Received: { resolvers: [[function HelloResolver]], validate: false } when using Type-graphql and apollo-server-express

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, graphql, apollo-server

I have been following this [full-stack tutorial by Ben Awad](https://youtu.be/I6ypD7qv3Z8?t=2716)
and when he added a resolver to the schema, everything went well, but when I tried the exact same code I get the error above. I am using graphql 15.5.1 and type-graphql 1.1.1 with apollo-server-express version 2.25.2. My code looks like this:

```html
import {Query, Resolver} from "type-graphql";

@Resolver()
export class HelloResolver {
    @Query(() => Number)
    hello() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

```html
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { buildSchema } from "graphql";
import {HelloResolver} from "./resolvers/hello";

const express = require('express');
const PORT : number = Number(process.env.PORT) || 3000;

const main = async () => {
    const apollo = new ApolloServer({
        schema: await buildSchema({
            // ERROR DUE TO LINE BELOW
            resolvers: [HelloResolver],
            validate: false,
        }),
    });

    apollo.applyMiddleware({ app });

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`);
    });
}

main().catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import { buildSchema } from "graphql";
```

should be

```
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
```

You can see that in [the same code linked in the video description](https://github.com/benawad/lireddit/blob/28011261643e466bb9258acf1f5c335582639201/server/src/index.ts#L6).